# Best Approach to Creating a USD LIBOR Forward Curve from Market Data

Tags: quantlib

This is a very basic question, I am convinced this has been answered before but I cannot seem to find it.

What is the best approach for constructing a USD Libor forward curve from market data?

For example, I am able to pull down the following forward/projection curves for USD Libor:

```
maturity   1M USD Libor   3M USD Libor   6M USD Libor   1Y USD Libor
1M          0.1551          0.2357         0.249          0.3658
3M          0.1622          0.2341         0.2473         0.3809
6M          0.1439          0.2051         0.2478         0.4081
1Y          0.1202          0.1948         0.2758         0.4797
2Y          0.1069          0.2265         0.3754         0.6704
3Y          0.2094          0.3452         0.5159         0.8479
4Y          0.392           0.5293         0.7074         1.0331
5Y          0.5843          0.7193         0.8862         1.2173
7Y          0.9077          1.0438         1.2055         1.5262
10Y         1.2002          1.3265         1.4985         1.763
15Y         1.255           1.3852         1.5278         1.7989
20Y         1.2285          1.3538         1.4866         1.7496
30Y         0.9059          1.0612         1.1455         1.3755
```

Note: For simplicity I have only included a selection of the rates along the curves I can access. In reality these are available to me at a daily frequency.

I have been attempting to import the above data (although I am not sure what Helper is most appropriate) with the end goal of using the resulting curve to forecast floating rates for valuing an IRS.

Edit: To clarify, the above curve might be best thought of as a forward-generating or projection curve. Its intended use is to project future 3M USD LIBOR rates.

Edit 2: The above curves are adjusted for tenor basis and I use a separate curve for discounting/valuation.

Comment: @DimitriVulis. Kind of but not exactly. The curve that I posted might be best thought of as nodes along what each of the examples you linked to intend to create (but adjusted specifically for the 3M tenor).

I am not sure if “forward curve” is the best terminology to describe the above curve, instead it might be described as a forward-generating or projection curve for specifically for 3M USD Libor.

I wonder if my best approach would be to build a generic Ibor curve using ql.IborIndex() but I am not sure what rate helper is best for importing the above curve.

Comment: your numbers are from FWCV on BBG?

Comment: DimitriVulis, When I wrote this up, I thought it would be simpler to focus on one tenor and chose 3M. In reality, I'll need to import the projection curves for the above tenors, as well as SIFMA, CMS and a few others. I edited the question to include the 4 LIBOR tenors and noted that these curves are already adjusted for tenor basis. In reality, all I am trying to do is import the rates and build a the corresponding curves but since they aren't really swap rates, deposit rates, etc, I am unsure of the best approach. As David suggests, I think these are most closely thought of as forward rates.

Answer (score 3):

If those numbers are only 3M rates, I'm affraid you don't have enough information to build a curve to value other instruments.

For example, you have a 3M rate starting in 1Y and in 2Y, but without the spot or swap rate, you have no information on the 3M fowards starting in 1Y3M, 1Y6M and 1Y9M...

I think one thing you could do is build a curve that does a flat interpolation of those rates using the `ql.ForwardCurve` class (expects continuous rates as inputs).

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodes = [
    ('1M', 0.2357),
    ('3M', 0.2341),
    ('6M', 0.2051),
    ('1Y', 0.1948),
    ('2Y', 0.2265),
    ('3Y', 0.3452),
    ('4Y', 0.5293),
    ('5Y', 0.7193),
    ('7Y', 1.0438),
    ('10Y', 1.3265),
    ('15Y', 1.3852),
    ('20Y', 1.3538),
    ('30Y', 1.0612),  
] 

today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
calendar = ql.TARGET()
dates = [calendar.advance(today, ql.Period(tenor)) for tenor, rate in nodes]
rates = [rate for tenor, rate in nodes]
dayCounter = ql.Actual360()
contRates = [ql.InterestRate(rate, dayCounter, ql.Compounded, ql.Quarterly).equivalentRate(ql.Continuous, ql.NoFrequency, 1).rate() for rate in rates]

curve = ql.ForwardCurve(dates, contRates, ql.Actual360())
curve.enableExtrapolation()

rates = [curve.forwardRate(dt, dt+ql.Period('3M'), ql.Actual360(),ql.Compounded, ql.Quarterly).rate() for dt, rate in curve.nodes()]
times = [dayCounter.yearFraction(today, dt) for dt, rate in curve.nodes()]
plt.plot(times, rates, 'o');
```

[image]

Notice that I plotted dots and not lines on purpose because what you actually get with this curve is flat interpolation of the forwards provided, ie:

```
allDates = ql.MakeSchedule(dates[0], curve.maxDate(), ql.Period('1D'))
allTimes = [dayCounter.yearFraction(today, dt) for dt in allDates]
fwds = [curve.forwardRate(dt, dt+ql.Period('3M'), ql.Actual360(),ql.Compounded, ql.Quarterly).rate() for dt in allDates]
plt.plot(allTimes, fwds)
```

[image]

Other alternatives would be to fit a curve to these points or use more advanced interpolation methods, although you probably have too few points for decent results on any of these alternatives.

Here is what the forward curve would look like using Monotone Convex interpolation.

[image]

Comment: David, I thought I was being helpful by only including a sample of the curve I have access to but I see that without stating as such I have caused a bit of confusion. In reality, I can pull the above curves with daily nodes. As a general question, how does one use interpolation with forward rates in quantlib (maybe this is my real question)? Both ql.FlatForward() and ql.ForwardCurve() do not seem to have an interpolation methods associated with them.

Comment: `ql.FlatForward` just builds a flat curve with a single rate and `ql.ForwardCurve` will do flat interpolation of the nodes you provide. If you have access to the data, why not just build the curves from the market instruments?

Answer (score 1):

You have more liquid instruments available to build your LIBOR curve, especially below the 5Y point. What we do usually is take all the eurodollar futures contracts below 5Y (so last one as of now would be the SEP25 contract) and apply a proper smooth convexity function (remember forward libor = eurodollar future + convexity). You need a convexity value for ech of those future contracts (20 contracts), and usually you can fit a smooth convexity (log polynomial for example) with 1Y,2Y,3Y,4Y,5Y swap points for example.
That way you have a more granular curve, and your forwards within the first 5 years are not subject to interpolation but calibrated to the market.